# React native webview push notification

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, push-notification

Nice to meet you. I'm Junior Developer And I can't speak English very well.
So, plz understand.

I want to create a hybrid app push function with react-native.

but, All I know is postmessage, onmessage.

Sending words typed on the web to the app and clicking a button in the app to send time to the web were successful.

I want to know if the push function we know is completed by using postmessage, onmessage, and push nofication.

- Android & iOS

And I'd like to know the site where I can refer to these techniques. thank you

-> Summary

**I want to make hybrid app + Push nofitication**

Comment: i didn't understand :(

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-notifications

Comment: @chikabala i'm so sorry

Comment: @Community i'm so sorry

Comment: @SangUlaeMustance check this : https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/823

Comment: @chikabala 
Thanks for the good information even for the lack of questions